# Database select one common field if conditions match

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm building Laravel 5.4 web application and I have below database table:

```
==================================
product_id|attribute_id|option_id
==================================
1         | 1          | 1
1         | 2          | 3
1         | 4          | 10
2         | 1          | 1
2         | 2          | 4
... etc
```

So i submit form with attributes id and options id so i can build array from it or whatever.

What i want to achieve that I select from the database the product_id which match exact combination for example:

```
[
attribute_id => 1,
option_id => 1

attribute_id => 2,
option_id => 3

attribute_id => 4,
option_id => 10
]
```

This condition only apply to product with product_id = 1

Don't know if i can do it using database query or by php.

Comment: what you want is like your example?

Comment: @MahmoudMustafa, If my answer is correct, please mark it as such so that other people can find it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a model that reflects your data. Then use the Eloquent query builder to get the data you're looking for. If you need just one number returned that matches, make sure to add on to the end the query "->distinct()".

You may also pass an array of conditions to the 'where' clause.

Your code may look something like this:

```
$match = DB::table('products')
                ->where('attribute_id', 1)
                ->where('option_id', 1)
                ->distinct()
                ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#introduction

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the product with product_id = 1
Assumed you have stored this in "product_attribute_option" table
and its fields are product_id |attribute_id | option_id as you shown.

```
      $query = DB::table('product_attribute_option as pao');
      $query->where('pao.product_id', 1);
      $results = $query->get();
```